# Can we assign the multiple cores of different hypervisors in same cluster?

Tags: windows, vps, cluster, cloud, hypervisor

I have configured the Three hypervisors with the OnApp.
As all the Hypervisors use the SAN storage, if any hypervisor gets down, VPS hosted on the one hypervisors boots on two hypervisors.

Each hypervisor has 12 cores, so the main question is can I assign the CPU cores of 2 hypervisors to a single VPS?

For example, hypervisor 1 has 12 cores, and hypervisor 2 has 12 cores, so can I assign 24 cores to a 1 VPS of that cluster?

Any answer or clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The nodes share storage. They are however not able to run a VM across nodes, and you probably would never want to do this, even if supported. The network bandwidth will be *much* lower than the memory bandwidth available locally, and the latency would be stiffling. A single VM can only run on one host.

Networks are 10Gb/s commonly; memory bandwidth is easily in the hundreds of gigabits, and the latency is in nanoseconds, not milliseconds.